# onSavedInstance always null in Activity and Fragment

Tags: android

I have two activities with one fragment each.  Activity A hosts Fragment A and Activity B hosts Fragment B.  I am saving some state information from Activity A and Fragment A when transitioning to Activity B.  When pressing the toolbar back button, the information saved previously is not available.  The savedInstanceState is always null in Activity A and Fragment A.  Here is my code in the simplest form.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_test"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.bigfootgames.android.myapp.MainActivity"/>
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
  private final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
  int loc;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate - savedInstanceState is " + (savedInstanceState == null ? "null" : "not null"));
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    if (fab != null)
    {
      fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
      {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
          loc = new Random().nextInt(10);

          Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TestActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState - savedInstanceState is " + (savedInstanceState == null ? "null" : "not null"));
    savedInstanceState.putInt("ActivityLocationInt", loc);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    Log.d(TAG, "onRestoreInstanceState - savedInstanceState is " + (savedInstanceState == null ? "null" : "not null"));
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    loc = savedInstanceState.getInt("ActivityLocationInt");
  }
}
```

MainActivityFragment.java:

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment
{
  private final String TAG = MainActivityFragment.class.getSimpleName();
  int loc;

  public MainActivityFragment()
  {
    loc = new Random().nextInt(10);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate - savedInstanceState is " + (savedInstanceState == null ? "null" : "not null"));
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView - savedInstanceState is " + (savedInstanceState == null ? "null" : "not null"));
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    return v;
  }

  @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityCreated - savedInstanceState is " + (savedInstanceState == null ? "null" : "not null"));
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null)
    {
      loc = savedInstanceState.getInt("FragmentLocationInt");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    Log.d(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState - savedInstanceState is " + (savedInstanceState == null ? "null" : "not null"));
    savedInstanceState.putInt("FragmentLocationInt", loc);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
  }
}
```

TestActivity.java:

```
public class TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
  private final String TAG = TestActivity.class.getSimpleName();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate - savedInstanceState is " + (savedInstanceState == null ? "null" : "not null"));
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
    {
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
  }
}
```

TestActivityFragment.java:

```
public class TestActivityFragment extends Fragment
{
  private final String TAG = TestActivityFragment.class.getSimpleName();

  public TestActivityFragment()
  {
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate - savedInstanceState is " + (savedInstanceState == null ? "null" : "not null"));
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView - savedInstanceState is " + (savedInstanceState == null ? "null" : "not null"));
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);

    return v;
  }
}
```

When I run the program, here are the log messages:

```
Start application:
    MainActivity:         onCreate - savedInstanceState is null
    MainActivityFragment: onCreate - savedInstanceState is null
    MainActivityFragment: onCreateView - savedInstanceState is null
    MainActivityFragment: onActivityCreated - savedInstanceState is null
Press floating action button to start Activity B:
    TestActivity:         onCreate - savedInstanceState is null
    TestActivityFragment: onCreate - savedInstanceState is null
    TestActivityFragment: onCreateView - savedInstanceState is null
    MainActivity:         onSaveInstanceState - savedInstanceState is not null
    MainActivityFragment: onSaveInstanceState - savedInstanceState is not null
Press toolbar back button to go back to Activity A:
    MainActivity:         onCreate - savedInstanceState is null
    MainActivityFragment: onCreate - savedInstanceState is null
    MainActivityFragment: onCreateView - savedInstanceState is null
    MainActivityFragment: onActivityCreated - savedInstanceState is null
```

The savedInstanceState variable is always null, except in the case of the onSaveInstanceState override function call to save the state.

What is the proper way to do this?  I have tried "singleTop" in the Manifest file, but that isn't what I wanted either.  I wanted to save and restore the state information.

I couldn't find any solid, up-to-date information on saving states with Activites and Fragments like this.  Regardless, the code doesn't save state for one or the other.  Is there something else I have to do?